# Justification for the nature of planet's orbit in gravitational field!

Tags: classical-mechanics, gravity, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion

In kleppner Mechanics in the chapter central force he derived the polar form of orbit for gravitational force as illustrated below: (first two equations are derived from fundamentals of central force)

[image]

[image]

**Often we are interested in the path of the particle, which means
knowing r as a function of θ rather than as a function of time.
We call r(θ) the orbit of the particle. (The term is used even if
the trajectory does not close on itself.) Dividing *Eq. (9.14)* by
*Eq. (9.12)* gives:**

[image]

**we  find  that  the  equation  for  the  orbit  ***Eq. (9.16)***  becomes,using  indefinite  integrals,**

[image]

[image]

---

Now my Questions:

1. why he takes dr/dt as positive(because all the terms in RHS in **eq(9.12)** is **positive**);? it is evidently **can be negative** and also from energy conservation it can be both positive and negative!
2. And as he has taken **it**(dr/dt) as positive that's why right side of **eq****(9.16)** is also is positive! But **for a conic section dθ/dr is not always positive!** It is positive for some interval and negative for some interval(actually 50:50)! so **eq(9.16) is only valid for** a certain interval (according to the choice of my coordinate system); but he(the writter of the book) derived the general solution not only for a certain interval but the total interval! Where am I getting wrong or how this is happening?

According to me something is **fishy in the integration of eq(9.16)** : the value of the integral doesn not hold everywhere in the interval of θ.    But I am not able to understand the matter properly!

Comment: Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! it's not necessary that $dr/dt$ is positive, it can be negative or it might be positive for some interval of time, and then again positive. This can be seen from the trajectory of comets themselves. Any comet which is in a parabolic trajectory came to attractor (some planet) with $dr/dt<0$ and then swing back making $dr/dt$ to be positive.

So you can take
$$\frac{dr}{dt}=-\sqrt{\cdots}$$
It makes no difference. Try by yourself!

---

To show this you might  wanna check it with your final result
$$\frac{dr}{dt}=-\frac{r_0}{(1-\epsilon\cos\theta)^2}(\epsilon \sin\theta)\frac{d\theta}{dt}$$
As you  can see  the sign of $dr/dt$ determine by the $\dot{\theta}$ and $\theta$. Note that sign of $\dot{\theta}$  depend only on initial  condition (look at the relation $\dot{\theta}=l/\mu r^2).$

You will also find taking $\theta_0=-\pi /2$ is crucial!

Comment: OK! But my main question is question 2. Thank you

Comment: Your second question is based on the result you have concluded from the first. If you have resolved the first question that implies that whatever written in the book is true!

Comment: But I am wondering when the differential equation is only valid for a certain interval then how that very equation has a solution for the total interval !? Or where am I getting wrong?

Comment: Yeah, it's a general misconception! I myself kind of find sometimes find it weird but it's not! What you have to keep in mind is that all the signs are consistent with the interval or situation perhaps, you are working with. For example, Suppose a particle is moving under harmonic potential in a viscous fluid where the viscous force is proportional to velocity and opposite in sign. So if you writing the equation of motion for the situation when its velocity is toward origin then you have to make the sign of force according to that that is away from the origin.

Comment: The solution would be valid for all intervals.